# Show underline to column header for GridView Sort

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView AllowSorting="true"  onsorting="grid_Sorting"....> 

     <asp:TemplateField ...> 
          <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="True" /> 
      </asp:TemplateField> 

     <asp:BoundField SortExpression="xyz"...> 
          <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="True" /> 
      </asp:BoundField> 

</asp:GridView>
```

I want to show GridView column header as underline so that user will undestand the header supports the sorting.
Right now only on mouse over it is showing underline to the column header.
I am using above code but still not getting underline to the Column Header.
What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<u>Your Header Text</u>"           
//define your template here        
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Simply add  tag to your header text. Change the header text to suit your needs.

For `BoundField` (actually for all), this will work i guess.

Add this between your `<head>` tag

```
<style>

th
{
   text-decoration:underline    
}

</style>
```

+1 if this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for taking time to answer...I tried that but <u></u> tag is coming in the output. Is there any way to give underline to the <BoundField> header text

Comment: No Success... :( the underline tag is coming in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below:USE `<u></u>` Tag inside HeaderTemplate

```
<asp:TemplateField><HeaderTemplate><u>TEXT</u></HeaderTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>

                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh..It is working for TemplateField,but What should I do for the BoundField Header Text??
Thanks in Advance